# How does one compare a string to the next string in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, compare

I'm writing a small NLP algorithm and I need to do the following:

For every string x in the list `["this", "this", "and", "that"]`, if the string `x` and the next string are identical, I want to print the string.

Answer (score 6):

```
s = ["this", "this", "and", "that"]
for i in xrange(1,len(s)):
    if s[i] == s[i-1]:
        print s[i]
```

EDIT:

Just as a side note, if you are using python 3.X use `range` instead of `xrange`

Answer (score 5):

```
strings = ['this', 'this', 'and', 'that']
for a, b in zip(strings, strings[1:]):
    if a == b:
        print a
```

Comment: This copies the list (well, except its first item) needlessly though.

Comment: I'm not even sure if its more readable/elegant than a simple loop through all elements ...

Comment: @FogleBird: Completely agreed - *for microoptimizations*. For things like these, (read: non-constant overhead), I'm more willing to think about it up-front. If OP is doing this with thirty-item lists, it's irrelevant. But if this is done on very long lists, it may become significant enough to warrant using a nearly equally simple and readable approach that avoids that overhead.

Comment: Should you need to iterate over a huge list (bigger than RAM), you can use `izip()` instead of `zip()` and `islice(strings, 1, None)` instead of `strings[1:]`, all from `itertools`.

Answer (score 2):

```
TEST = ["this", "this", "and", "that"]
for i, s in enumerate(TEST):
   if i > 0 and TEST[i-1] == s:
      print s

# Prints "this"
```

Answer (score 2):

Most Pythonic is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is exactly built for looping and testing at the same time:

```
>>> strings = ['this', 'this', 'and', 'that']

>>> [a for (a,b) in zip(strings, strings[1:]) if a==b]

['this']
```

Or, to avoid temporary objects (h/t @9000):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> [a for (a,b) in it.izip(strings, it.islice(strings,1)) if a==b]

['this']
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, I like to stick with old-fashioned loops:

```
strings = ['this', 'this', 'and', 'that']
for i in range(0, len(strings)-1):
   if strings[i] == strings[i+1]:
      print strings[i]
```

Everyone knows what's going on without much thinking, and it's fairly efficient...

Answer (score 1):

why not simply ? :

```
strings = ['this', 'this', 'and', 'that', 'or', 'or', 12,15,15,15, 'end']

a = strings[0]
for x in strings:
    if x==a:
        print x
    else:
        a = x
```

Comment: This will always print the firth element in `strings` since a and x both start as strings[0].

Answer (score 0):

Is that homework?

```
l = ["this", "this", "and", "that", "foo", "bar", "bar", "baz"]

for i in xrange(len(l)-1):
   try:
      if l.index(l[i], i+1) == i+1:
         print l[i]
   except ValueError:
      pass
```

Comment: I really don't see why you use the try/except statement ?? I will simply use a print str(l[i]) and it's gonna be ok :)

Comment: list.index() throws a ValueError exception if the item is not found. That's why.

Comment: the only way it could happen is if you delete an item between the range and the print ? :/

Comment: As the documentation for list.index() says: "Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item."

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you're processing over items in a list and you need to look at the current item's neighbors, you're going to want to use `enumerate`, since `enumerate` gives you both the current item and its position in the list.

Unlike the approaches that use `zip`, this list comprehension requires no duplication of the list:

```
print [s for i, s in enumerate(test[:-1]) if s == test[i + 1]]
```

Note that it fails if there aren't at least two elements in `test`, and that `test` must be a list.  (The `zip` approaches will work on any iterable.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little different approach that uses a special class to detect repeats in a sequence. Then you can actually find the repeats using a simple list comprehension.

```
class repeat_detector(object):
    def __init__(self, initial=None):
        self.last = initial
    def __call__(self, current):
        if self.last == current:
            return True
        self.last = current
        return False

strings = ["this", "this", "and", "that"]

is_repeat = repeat_detector()

repeats = [item for item in strings if is_repeat(item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the recipe for `pairwise()` from the stdlib [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) documentation (I'll quote it here):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

And you can do:

```
for a, b in pairwise(L):
    if a == b:
        print a
```

Or with a generator expression thrown in:

```
for i in (a for a, b in pairwise(L) if a==b):
    print i
```